# Remove webapss icon from launcher and switcher

Tags: unity, launcher, webapps, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I keep webapps from appearing in launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206689/how-do-i-keep-webapps-from-appearing-in-launcher)

I like the Webapps integration in Sound/Messaging Menus, but I don't need them to be in my launcher when they are running and neither do I want them in my switcher. 
In case I need the apps, I can move to the desired tab myself through Firefox.
(In combination with grouping tabs, the launcher/switcher icons will not even move to the right tab, but even if it would do that, I would not be interested)